# Is it possible to control the eq settings of the Kalimba DSP by a Bluetooth (Android) App?

Tags: android, audio-dsp

We use the CSRA64215 to stream audio by Bluetooth to our audio hardware. Now this chip has a Kalimba DSP integrated. Is it possible to control the DSP's EQ settings by Bluetooth for example via AVRCP or similar? We would like to create an android app to achieve this. I am very new to this kind of engineering, can someone give me a hint?

Maybe you can map the simple events that are controllable by java bluetooth like play or pause etc. via avrcp to the eq settings. I will do some research into that direction and post the results. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why the down & close votes? And why not have the politeness to tell the OP what you think he is doing wrong with this post, in order that he can do better in future?  This seems like a good question to me; if you think that it ought to be asked on another S.E site, please state which. We are supposed to be trying to help here. This is ***not*** the way to build a community !

Comment: To be constructive, where is the documentation for this device? If it is NDA only, you really need to be talking direct to the vendor. Is there more information you can share about the architecture of your design that will help us to answer? Remember that there may not be anyone here who has done exactly what you're asking, but will have done similar things with other devices. Make it easy for us to help you...

Comment: Please notify the IP owner following the email address in the first page of that document.